# Using a ToggleSwitch in App Settings

Tags: windows-phone-8, toggleswitch

I want to use ToggleSwitch in the app settings. I am not able to save its state on IsolatedStorage so that it can be reflected on the MainPage. I have tried using the available Key/Value pair storage examples on msdn to perform this but have not been able to. Please write a precise solution if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

1. in your settings page XAML

   ```
   <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="Push Notifications" 
   Checked="PushNotificationsToggle_Checked" Unchecked="PushNotificationsToggle_Unchecked">
   </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
   ```
2. in your settings page code behind

   ```
   private void PushNotificationsToggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
       settings["PushNotifications"] = false;
       settings.Save();
   }
   ```
3. in your main page you can use this setting like this

   ```
   var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
   Boolean usePushNotifications = (Boolean)settings["PushNotifications"]
   ```